# I can't upload sketches to my Arduino 101

Tags: arduino-101

When connected to USB green Power LED on but doesn't upload sketch(that says press master reset therefore i've pressed several time but timeout). And main thing is device doesn't show in device manager.(I'm working on windows10).

- Have I "bricked" it?
- What steps can I take to work out what is wrong?
- What can I do to fix it?

I've search in many sites but doesn't give me detail about hardware repairing guide for arduino 101.

I've checked working usb cable and another laptop but not work.I think **hardware problem**.Once arduino getting hot near usb.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply replace it because it has a 1 year warranty outside the US.

Comment: It's considered rude to post things in all caps online. I have fixed this for you but please don't do it again. Please add some more details to your answer to make it more helpful: What kind of process was required for the replacement? How did you contact customer service How prompt was their response? Did you have to return the Arduino 101 to get your replacement? If so, were return shipping charges paid by Arduino and was the return address in your country? What sort of restrictions are there for people in the US who need a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but you can try a lot of options:

- Use another USB port
- Use another USB cable
- Reinstall the Arduino IDE
- Remove the device in the device manager and try reinstalling the Arduino IDE again
- Try another Arduino (to see if the USB/install is ok)
- Try on a different computer/laptop

Comment: I've also checked all this but i think it's hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked all of the above as *Michel Keijzers* mentioned then it might be a hardware problem. Actually, your usb cable might not fitting correctly to the usb port.